# Disabling trace statements in Flex 3

Tags: flex3, flash

My Application's UI is built in Flex 3. We have used trace statements at multiple locations, which are being logged in flashlog.txt file.

I build application with mxmlc ant task and providing debug="true"

Now, I don't want to print trace statements every time I run my application, So I build it by removing debug statement from ant task. It still prints my debug info in the same file.
Is there anything which I am doing wrong to fulfill the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
debug="false"
```

? :)

Comment: Yes, I did try that. No success.

Comment: http://mail.flashcodersny.org/pipermail/flashcodersny_flashcodersny.org/2009-May/011831.html also read all the comments there..

Comment: Thanks for this info, but I am still not able to find the proper way, without making any changes in .as or .mxml files, how would I achieve this?

Comment: hmm maybe it's just your debug player who prints those infos. have you tested your app with a release player?

Comment: Well, release player does not log traces. Only debug player logs traces.

Comment: it's written in the previous link that they couldn't remove the trace instructions.. so any debug player will display the traces... but I don't know if this is still true..